# ListView with several edittext fields

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have a ListView based on a RelatieLayout with several TextViews and one EditText. One of the textfields gets updated based on what the value in the EditText-field is.

My problem is to preserve the value of the editText-field when scrolling the listView. My extention of BaseAdapter looks like this:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

static class ItemViewHolder {
    TextView
        itemName,
        itemPrize,
        itemTotalPrize,
    EditText
        itemAmount;
}   

static class CatViewHolder {
    TextView
        categoryName;
    Button
        categoryInfo;
}

ArrayList<ListItem> itemsList;
HashMap<Integer, String> volume = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

public ListViewAdapter(ArrayList<ListItem> itemsList) {
    this.itemsList = itemsList;
}   

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.itemList.size();
}

@Override
public ListItem getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.itemList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (getItem(position).isCategory()) return 0;
        else return 1;
}   

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;     
    if (!getItem(position).isCategory()) {
        String[] string;// = {"", ""};
        final Item item = (Item) getItem(position);
        if (row == null) {
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ItemViewHolder();
            viewHolder.itemName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
            viewHolder.itemPrize = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.itemPrize);
            viewHolder.itemTotalPrize = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.itemTotalPrize);                
            viewHolder.itemAmount = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.itemAmount);
            row.setTag(viewHolder);
        }   else viewHolder = (DrugViewHolder) row.getTag();
        viewHolder.itemName.setText(item.getName());
        viewHolder.itemPrize.setText(String.valeuOf(item.getPrize()));
        viewHolder.itemAmount.addTextChangedListener(new AmountTextWatcher(item, position, row));
        viewHolder.itemAmount.setText(volume.get(item.getId)));
        viewHodler.itemTotalPrize.setText(String.valueOf(item.getPrize() * volume.get(item.getId));
    }   else {
            Category category = (Category) getItem(position);
            if (row == null) {
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category, parent, false);
                catViewHolder = new CatViewHolder();
                catViewHolder.categoryName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.categoryName);
                catViewHolder.categoryInfo = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.categoryInfo);
                row.setTag(catViewHolder);
            }   else catViewHolder = (CatViewHolder) row.getTag();
            catViewHolder.categoryName.setText(category.getCatName());
        }
return row;     
}
@Override
public void AmountTextWatcher_interface(String amount, int position) {
    volume.put(position, amount);
}
```

**Edit, added ListItem-structure**

ListItem class that looks like this :

```
package com.buy.ng;
    public interface ListItem {
    public boolean isCategory();
}
```

My two objects, item and cateogory implements ListItem and isCategory() is overridden in both item and cateogry. Item returns false and the category returns true.

My AmountTextWatcher looks like this:

```
class AmountTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

public AmountTextWatcher_Interface textChangedListener = null;

interface AmountTextWatcher_Interface {
    public abstract void AmountTextWatcher_interface(String amount, int position);
}

private static final String TAG = "amountTextWatcher";

private TextView textView_TotalPrize,
private Item item;

public PrizeTextWatcher(Item item, int position, View row) {
    this.row = row;
    this.item = item;
    this.textView_TotalPrize = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.itemTotalPrize);
}

@Override       
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    String amount = s.toString().replace(",", ".").trim();
    int dummy;

    if (amount.length() == 0 || amount == null ) amount = "0";

    try {
        dummy = Integer.valueOf(amount);
    }   catch (NumberFormatException npe) {
            amount= "0";
            EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.itemAmount);
            editText.setText("");
        }
    this.textView_prize.setText(Intege.valueOf(amount) * item.getPrize());
    textChangedListener.PrizeTextWatcher_interface(amount, item.getId());
}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
}
}
```

I've tried several approaches, but I can't get the value in the amount EditText-field to be preserved on ListView scroll.

I've tried HashMap amount = new HashMap(); and populate this with values entered in the EditText, volume.put(item.getId(), amount), but I can't seem to get it right.

Tried an interface with this PrizeTextWatcher that has amount and item.getId() as variable. This interface is implemented in the ListViewAdapter and it modifes the HashMap volume within this adapter like this :

```
@Override
public void AmountTextWatcher_interface(String amount, int id) {
    volume.put(id, amount);
}
```

Any suggestions or am I doing this all wrong? As a relative newbie in android, I find this quite difficult to achive...

Comment: About which EditText are you talking ? `viewHolder.itemAmount = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.itemAmount);` or `EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.amount);` ? You should at least fill the mentioned EditText in getView() with the saved entered value. The user is entering values in that editdtext? You are unclear about that. Start to care that text which is entered is saved and put back when the user scrolls the list. You can use a String ArrayList for that.

Comment: Sorry. Typos. There is only one EditText in the RelativeLayout and it is called itemAmount. The user enters a value in the EditText-field or it gets set from a value in a SparseArray. My problem is, it's called volume in the code above, I cant seem to save and retrive the correct value. In the getView() I set the itemAmount EditText with viewHolder.itemAmount.setText(volume.get(item.getId)));, and i try to set it in the textwatcher interface by volume.put(item.getId(), amount). But it doesnt work. I might have starred me blind on this. Maybe a beer and a good night sleeps will help...

Answer (score 0):

Update This code

```
@Override 
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    return position; 
}
```

Comment: your code is complex , it can be achieve in simple code also

Comment: can u share me with ListItem structure

Comment: Added the ListView struture in the original post!

Answer (score 0):

Choose to answer my own question with a somewhat working version of this kind of ListView. There are some userexperience-problems, but this BaseAdapter handles edittext-fields.

What is the main difference between the code in my question and the code in my answer?

**Three ViewHolders**

I thought I could just remove the EditText-field from the views that didn't need an editText-field. Wrong. Or atleast it works with three ViewHolders.

**OnFocusChange**

Use of OnFocusChange instead of addTextChangedListener. Modifies the adpater-dataset directly from here and voila!

**requestFocusFromTouch**

viewHolder.itemAmount.requestFocusFromTouch(); gives the editText focus when touched.

In the manifest, add

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

to your activity.

In the the XML-Listview, add

```
android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
```

Some argue that "*beforeDescendants*" should be used in the XML-ListView. Doesn't change anything in my examplecode.

The adpater looks like this:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

static class ItemViewHolderEditText {
    TextView
        itemName,
        itemPrize,
        itemTotalPrize,
    EditText
        itemAmount;
}   

static class ItemViewHolder {
    TextView
        itemName,
        itemPrize,
        itemTotalPrize,
}   

static class CatViewHolder {
    TextView
        categoryName;
}

ArrayList<ListItem> itemsList;
Item item;

public ListViewAdapter(ArrayList<ListItem> itemsList) {
    this.itemsList = itemsList;
}   

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.itemsList.size();
}

@Override
public ListItem getItem(int position) {
    return this.itemsList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (getItem(position).isCategory()) return 0;
        else {
            item = (Item) getItem(position);
            if (item.hasEditText()) return 1;
            return 2;
        }
}   

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;     
    if (!getItem(position).isCategory()) {
        item = (Item) getItem(position);
        if (item.hasEditText()) {
            if (row == null) {
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_edittext, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ItemViewHolderEditText();
                viewHolder.itemName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
                viewHolder.itemPrize = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.itemPrize);
                viewHolder.itemTotalPrize = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.itemTotalPrize);                
                viewHolder.itemAmount = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.itemAmount);
                row.setTag(viewHolder);
            }   else viewHolder = (ItemViewHolderEditText) row.getTag();
            viewHolder.itemName.setText(item.getName());
            viewHolder.itemPrize.setText(String.valeuOf(item.getPrize()));
            viewHolder.itemAmount.setId(position);
            viewHolder.itemAmount.requestFocusFromTouch();
            viewHolder.itemAmount.selectAll();
            viewHolder.itemAmount.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if (!hasFocus){
                        final EditText amount = (EditText) v;
                        Item item = (Item) itemsList.get(position);
                        item.setTotalPrize(Double.valueOf(amount.getText().toString().trim()));
                        itemsList.set(v.getId(), item);
                    }
                }
            });     
            viewHolder.itemAmount.setText(volume.get(item.getId)));
            viewHodler.itemTotalPrize.setText(String.valueOf(item.getPrize() * volume.get(item.getId));
        }   else {
                if (row == null) {
                    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
                    viewHolder = new ItemViewHolder();
                    viewHolder.itemName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
                    viewHolder.itemPrize = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.itemPrize);
                    viewHolder.itemTotalPrize = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.itemTotalPrize);                
                    row.setTag(viewHolder);
                }   else viewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) row.getTag();
                viewHolder.itemName.setText(item.getName());
                viewHolder.itemPrize.setText(String.valeuOf(item.getPrize()));
                viewHodler.itemTotalPrize.setText(item.getTotalPrize());
            }
    }   else {
            Category category = (Category) getItem(position);
            if (row == null) {
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category, parent, false);
                catViewHolder = new CatViewHolder();
                catViewHolder.categoryName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.categoryName);
                catViewHolder.categoryInfo = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.categoryInfo);
                row.setTag(catViewHolder);
            }   else catViewHolder = (CatViewHolder) row.getTag();
            catViewHolder.categoryName.setText(category.getCatName());
        }
    return row;     
}
```